# What is query_hash in instagram?

Tags: graphql

I was working for the first time on graphql, and I saw that Instagram hash their queries.

I searched something, but I don't know if it is correct. The hash is like a persistedquery stored in a cache memory?

Or am I wrong?

Example: this is my request payload

```
{
 "operationName":"user",
 "variables":{},
 "query":"query user {\n  users {\n    username\n    createdAt\n    _id\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

this is instagram:

```
 query_hash: 60b755363b5c230111347a7a4e242001
 variables: %7B%22only_stories%22%3Atrue%7D
```

(it is in urlencode mode).

Now, how could I hash my query? I'm using NodeJS as backend and react js as frontend. 
I would like to understand how it works x)! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The persisted query is used to improve GraphQL network performance by reducing the request size.

Instead of sending a full query which could be very long, you send a hash to the GraphQL server which will retrieve the full query from the key-value store using the hash as the key.

The key value store can be `memcached`, `redis`, etc

The Apollo Server comes with **automated persisted queries** out of the box. I recommended gives it a try. They have publish a blog about it. https://blog.apollographql.com/automatic-persisted-queries-and-cdn-caching-with-apollo-server-2-0-bf42b3a313de

If you want to build your own solution, you can use this package to do the hashing yourself https://www.npmjs.com/package/hash.js

Comment: Just another question: the cache is different foreach user or not? It's like a database stored server-side (so, the same for all user) and not client-side ?

Comment: The hash is different based on the query content, it’s has nothing to do with the user. And yes, it’s stored on the server only

Comment: Does the hash expires or changes for each type of query content?

Answer (score 3):

`query_hash` (or `query_id`) does not hash the variables or the parameters, it hashes the payload.
Lets say your actual path is `/graphql` and your payload is

```
{
    "user": {
        "profile": [
            "username",
            "user_id",
            "profile_picture"
        ],
        "feed": {
            "posts": {
                "data": [
                    "image_url"
                ],
                "page_size": "{{variables.max_count}}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this graphql payload will be hashed and it becomes `d4d88dc1500312af6f937f7b804c68c3`. Now instead of doing that on `/graphql` you do `/graphql/query/?query_hash=d4d88dc1500312af6f937f7b804c68c3`. This way you hashed the payload, as in you hashed the "keys" that are required from the graphql. So when you pass `variables` as a `param` then the payload does not actually change, because the variables are constant as well, and you are changing them on the backend, and not in the payload.